# How can I build a diamond shaped minecart track?

Tags: terraria

[Terraria's wiki](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/The_Torch_God) suggests preparing for a battle against the Torch God via building a "diamond"-shaped minecart track. At the time of this posting, it reads:

> Making a diamond shape out of minecart rails around a 10x10 of torches allows for a cheap, effortless, and 0 damage victory. Just make sure to hammer the rails so the player can circle the torches making use of bumpers and rail intersections as necessary.

However, I cannot seem to get a minecart track to fold into anything close to a diamond shape. Somehow I was able to hammer the top-most intersection into a nice, clean curve but haven't been able to reproduce that elsewhere. My latest attempt is below. Note that the top angle is perfect, the bottom is acceptable but not perfect, and I have no idea if it's possible to cleanly connect the left and right corners.

Is it possible to create a diamond shape with smooth edges allowing a continuous ride in one direction without additional button presses? If so, how?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make a diamond shape that you can go around continuously by holding one direction, but it won't have smooth edges. The wiki page's mention of bumpers and intersections leads me to believe it should look something like this style of Skeletron Arena, but smaller:

[image: Diamond of Minecart Track with Bumpers]

The extreme left and right ends of the track have been hammered to be "bumper" endings that reverse the direction of the minecart, while also reversing any currently held movement key so the player can hold a single direction the whole time. Letting go of your movement key will restore your usual controls. The two intersections near the the bumpers have been hammered to direct the minecart around in a loop. Besides those, everything is normally placed track.

Starting anywhere in the diamond and holding either direction will soon result in moving counter-clockwise around the diamond. One could easily hammer the intersections differently to go around clockwise instead.

And there's rail at the top that I couldn't fit on screen, of course. That rail in the bottom left was just a way to get onto the diamond, and can be ignored for Torch God purposes.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much!